# Postgresql :i want tro truncate column

Tags: postgresql

I have

```
select * from generale where titolo  ~* 'hp-ux' order by titolo;
      autori       |                                                   titolo                                                    |        casaeditrice        
-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------
 Asghar Ghori      | HP Certified Systems Administrator: Hp-ux 11i V3: Exam Hp0-a01: Training Guide and Adminstrator's Reference | Endeavor Technologies Inc.
 Autori vari       | HP-UX tuning and performance                                                                                | Prentice Hall
```

The line title is very long for Book Entry Hp Certified...etc,etc
I want to truncate to this

```
 Asghar Ghori      | HP Certified Systems Administrator:....
```

The ... are not important i want to truncate column output to max 20 characters,
on oracle i use `column titolo format a20` how to do this on postgres?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
select autori, substring(titolo,1,20) || '...'
from generale where titolo  ~* 'hp-ux' order by titolo;
```

it truncates your output but doesn't touch the data in the table

Comment: nice,and if i want to call with a name?I have tried `select autori, substring(titolo,1,20) as titolo|| '...'
from generale where titolo  ~* 'hp-ux' order by titolo;` but give error

Comment: select autori, substring(titolo,1,20) || '...' AS titolo
from generale where titolo  ~* 'hp-ux' order by titolo;